# Perform Method on all entries on the whole Ruby class (using Rails framework)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, activerecord

I am trying to write a method that selects a subset of all members of the User class. Here is my attempt:

```
 def self.stats_users(date)                                                
   self.where("employee = false AND last_sign_in_at >= ?", date)          
 end
```

I tried to call this function in this manner: `User.stats_user('2011-04-14')`

However, this method is executing this sql statement:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (employee = false AND last_sign_in_at >= '2011-04-14')
```

when it should simply execute:

```
SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE (employee = false AND last_sign_in_at >= '2011-04-14')
```

I guess my real question revolves around writing methods that act on all members of a class and my relative ignorance of where to put these methods and how to call them. I also appear to be having a little trouble understanding how ActiveRecord transforms statements into raw sql.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no difference betwen those two SQL queries. Can someone explain how they might be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### RE SQL

The queries are equivalent in this case.

#### RE methods for collections

This what [scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html) are for:

```
scope :stats_users, lambda { |date| 
  where("employee = false AND last_sign_in_at >= ?",date)
}
```

Comment: The same as you would the class method. However you can also chain them.